# How do I create an image overlay and add to MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I am trying to learn MapKit and am now trying to add an image as an overlay to the map view.
I can't seem to find any sample code to help explain how to do this.

Can you guys please help me how to create `MKOverlay`s and add them to `MKMapKit`.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't know if I have understood exactly your questione. Shortly, I'd need to use MKPointAnnotation not upon a map but upon a picture captured from the smartphone camera. So I should work with annotations on a picture. is this what you wanted to to doo when you asked about MKOverlay?

Comment: @Jr Ntr Achanta : Go through below tutorials.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 25):

Here is an example to how to sets a `UIImage` to a `MKMapView` overlay. Some parameter (coordinates and image path) are fixed, but the code can be easily changed, I guess.

Create an class that conforms to `MKOverlay`:

MapOverlay.h

```
@interface MapOverlay : NSObject <MKOverlay> {

}

- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

MapOverlay.m

```
@implementation MapOverlay

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {


    }
    return self;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = {
        37.434999,-122.16121
    };

    return coord1;
}

- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect
{

    MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.coordinate);

    MKMapRect bounds = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, 2000, 2000);
    return bounds;
}


@end
```

Create an class that conforms to MKOverlayView:

MapOverlayView.h

```
@interface MapOverlayView : MKOverlayView {

}

@end
```

MapOverlayView.m

```
@implementation MapOverlayView

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

    UIImage *image          = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] retain];

    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect    = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect           = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];
    CGRect clipRect     = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];

    CGContextAddRect(ctx, clipRect);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, theRect, imageReference);

    [image release]; 

}


@end
```

Add the overlay to the MKMapView:

```
MapOverlay * mapOverlay = [[MapOverlay alloc] init];
[mapView addOverlay:mapOverlay];
[mapOverlay release];
```

On the mapView delegate, implement the viewForOverlay:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MapOverlay *mapOverlay = overlay;
    MapOverlayView *mapOverlayView = [[[MapOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:mapOverlay] autorelease];

    return mapOverlayView;

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: worked quite well!  What would be great is if this image is always drawn to the mapView.bounds.  Right now it is drawn into the extents of the boundingMapRect, which can be much bigger than the current viewableRect of the mapView

Comment: What are the lines above the implementation supposed to look like?  Does the OverlayView need to be created as a subclass of UIView, or NSObject?

Comment: Your code works like a charm, though I am still unclear on just what type of subclass I was creating on New File.  In any case, I fit your code into Apple's MapCallouts sample and didn't know that my image was being drawn too small.  Changing it to an all black image of 2000x2000 pixels actually displayed it at a tiny size.  I'm on the right track thanks to you.  Cheers.

Comment: i found that the image was appearing upsidedown. found that this worked better.

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    MKMapRect theMapRect    = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect           = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];
    
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [_image drawInRect:theRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}

Comment: Actually, MKMapPoint upperLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.coordinate); does not do what you seem to think it does: self.coordinate, being an implementation of the MKOverlay protocol, returns "The approximate center point of the overlay area" according to the documentation, not the upper left point.

Comment: somehow fails to present the image on my mapView

Answer (score 2):

Documentation:

- [MKMapView functions to manage overlays](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW50) allow for adding them to a map view.
- [MKOverlay](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKOverlay) is the protocol which your overlay object must conform to.

  - [MKPolygon](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolygon_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009717), [MKPolyLine](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolyline_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009719), [MKCircle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009710) implement this protocol for simple shapes.
- [MKOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009715) is used to actually draw the overlay; subclasses exist for each of the above-mentioned simple shapes.

Sample code:

- [HazardMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049)
- [KMLViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046)

Comment: @Marc W: Because it's just a big list of links to documentation, I didn't really contribute anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the search for a solution for my problem, I keep coming back to this question, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249890/how-to-convert-cgrect-to-maprect) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553072/how-to-check-if-mkcoordinateregion-contains-cllocationcoordinate2d-without-using)

They were all answering the question I needed answered but in reverse.

I needed to determine if a UIView, i.e. a draw square on my MapView contains a map pin, if it does let me know so I can remove it or select it etc.

Finally after trying to convert my UIView into some MKCoordinateRegion or alike, I thought work backwards. Instead of turning my UIView or square into map madness, I turned the pins into simple CGPoints and did a simple Rect contains point. Which ended up being my solution.. after about 2 hrs!

Hope this help someone down the line

```
 func findMapPinsWithinBox() {

    guard let myBox = myBox else { return } // some UIView you have drawn or placed on map

    let visibleMapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect
    let visibleAnnotations =  mapView.annotationsInMapRect(visibleMapRect)

    for pin in visibleAnnotations {

        // depending on design you may need to do some casting here
        // ie let pin = pin as! MyMapAnnotation

        let pinsCGPoint = mapView.convertCoordinate(pin.coordinate, toPointToView: self.view)

        if myBox.frame.contains(pinsCGPoint) {
            print("Pin Found within the Box")
            // select pin or delete etc
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From just looking at Apple's documentation for the [`MKOverlay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKOverlay) protocol, it doesn't look very complex. Just make a class to do whatever you need to compute the overlay and make sure it conforms to that protocol. That means you must have the `coordinate` and `boundingMapRect` properties as well as an implementation for `intersectsMapRect:`. The Apple docs explain it all.

Take a look at the [HazardMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010049) sample code from Apple. It uses a custom overlay view like you want to do to display an image in the overlay. You simply need to implement `mapView:viewForOverlay:` in your `MKMapViewDelegate` class and return a new instance of your subclass of `MKOverlayView` to get the custom overlay drawn on the screen.