# Use custom map image in UIMapView

Tags: ipad, ios4, mkoverlay, mkmapview

I wanna accomplish the following, i wanna display a static map image that i have on `UIMapView` to use the benefits of the zooming and annotation, i've search very hard and i came up with these solution.

1. There is a library called [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) that give you the ability to customize the map, change the color of the map, specify a predefined road and building, highlight them, but it didn't help me in my issue.
2. I've looked on apple example that using the `MKOverLay` class, HazardMap, KMLViewer but they are not showing how to use an image to replace it with the map.

All i want is to display a map image that i have for a place and use it in UIMapView. can anyone put me in the right direction.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied to this question in this other post. Maybe it helps you:

[How do I create an image overlay and add to MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283741/how-do-i-create-an-image-overlay-and-add-to-mkmapview)

Comment: I've implement your solution, but the image does not appear, can you help me with it ?

Comment: I've managed to let it work using '[mapViews setVisibleMapRect:[mapOverlay boundingMapRect]];' thank you for answer, but i'm looking for a better one.

Comment: Please tell me if you find one better. Thanks.