# How to add overlay to UIImage in a UIButton

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, colors

in Objective C, for iPhone/iPad
Im struggling trying to change the color (red/yellow/green) of a UIImage, in a UIButton.
How can this be done. Is a subclass required?
Can someone please provide an example.

i.e. this is a full single color overlay.

Comment: Refer from here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6554418/932011

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to place a semi-transparent image mask on top of a UIButton (this won't exactly change the color, but can add colored shadow effects), then create a semi-transparent PNG, add it to your Supporting Files group, and then add the following line of code in some place like `viewDidLoad` for a view controller to add the mask on top of the UIButton:

```
[myButton addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"]]];
```