# Fire local Notification on users reaching certain location without using map

Tags: ios, geolocation, notifications, location

I have a set of different longitudes and latitudes, now I want to fire the notification when user reaches to one of those location. I'm using `[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]` to search in background. Is there any way such that we can fire the notification if the user enters in that region? or is there any way such that we will know that the user has entered that particular location?? And one more thing, i'm not using any map view to show the user location rather, i dont want to....

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [How to check if MKCoordinateRegion contains CLLocationCoordinate2D without using MKMapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553072/how-to-check-if-mkcoordinateregion-contains-cllocationcoordinate2d-without-using) . As you are not using MapView, you need to get the current region and apply the logic as given in this link.

Comment: yeh...m getting the current region with the help of didUpdateToLocation: delegate method and now i'm trying to monitor that region using startMonitoringForRegion: but didEnterRegion method is not getting called...i'm new to these location things..

Comment: Not sure but trying to help you http://www.creativebloq.com/ipad/get-started-geofencing-ios-9122867