# How to put my own map in MKMapView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I need create an app for iOS using the GPS and MapKit. The idea is create my own map of my house for example and add it to the UIView or MKMapView and see the current position into the map.

see the image

[image]

Comment: You could possibly overlay an image ( your house plan) on top of the uimapview see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283741/how-do-i-create-an-image-overlay-and-add-to-mkmapviewx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom overlay on the map. [Here](http://code4app.net/ios/Custom-Map-Overlay/51ef3e0e6803faf51f000005) is nice example of image overlay on the `mapView`.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided sample code to do this with map tiles. Using the MapKnitter website you can  geoposition your floor plan and export it in a format that Apple's code will accept.